# dynamodb partition key for questions table

Tags: database-design, amazon-dynamodb

The main table for my app will hold questions. Which one of the below options would be a better choice for partition key?

1. Keep the question itself as the partition key. The questions can be upto 200 chars long
2. use redis to keep track of a counter and use that as partition key

Comment: Another possibility is to create a composite key based on a timestamp and perhaps the unique id of the user who asked the question, where the hash key is the user id and the time is the range key. This about the queries you'll be making the most often and how you could implement them efficiently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choosing option 1 would be the **biggest mistake ever** because whenever you search for that question you need to pass exactly the same value as it holds in table even a character different would result in question not found.

You can go with option 2 which is to have a random hash key which is tracked from redis. This would be helpful in querying the data from DynamoDB.

Another advantage would be that there is less chance of HOT keys, which will eventually lead to Throughput problems with the table.

Refer [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html#GuidelinesForTables.Partitions) of best practices for further help.